# Unable to store GeoJson Polygon object in Mongodb using Morphia with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, polygon, geojson, morphia

I am trying to store a GeoJson Polygon object to Mongodb using Morphia. Please note that GeoJson Polygon coordinates have to be 3 level deep array like below.

```
{
  type: "Polygon",
  coordinates: [ [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 3 , 6 ] , [ 6 , 1 ] , [ 0 , 0  ] ] ]
}
```

Following is my Entity class.

```
static class Loc {
        private final String type = "Polygon";
        private ArrayList<ArrayList<Double[]>> coordinates = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double[]>>();
        public ArrayList<ArrayList<Double[]>> getCoordinates() {
            return coordinates;
        }
        public void setCoordinates(ArrayList<Double[]> coordinates) {
            this.coordinates.add(coordinates);

        }
    }
```

When I store it, Morphia gives me following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error mapping field:com.utils.JavaUtils$Poly.loc
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:983)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:593)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.entityToDBObj(DatastoreImpl.java:1359)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:1279)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:775)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:758)
    at com.utils.JavaUtils.polygonizeAndSave(JavaUtils.java:105)
    at com.examples.MainExample$$anonfun$main$4.apply(MainExample.scala:71)
    at com.examples.MainExample$$anonfun$main$4.apply(MainExample.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at com.examples.MainExample$.main(MainExample.scala:71)
    at com.examples.MainExample.main(MainExample.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


     Caused by: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error mapping field:com.utils.JavaUtils$Poly$Loc.coordinates
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:983)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:593)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.toDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:98)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.writeMappedField(Mapper.java:875)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:981)
    ... 21 more 


    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [className]
    at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:168)
    at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:160)
    at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList.removeField(BasicBSONList.java:117)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.writeCollection(EmbeddedMapper.java:243)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.toDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:90)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.writeMappedField(Mapper.java:875)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:981)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same exact problem and came to following conclusion. Instead of using your custom class, you should use what Morphia provides you with. Mainly you can just create your polygon like this:

```
import org.mongodb.morphia.geo.Point;
import org.mongodb.morphia.geo.Polygon;
import org.mongodb.morphia.geo.GeoJson;

public class Main {
    private static PlaceDAO placeDAO = ...;

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Place place = new Place();

        Point point1 = GeoJson.point(0.0, 0.0);
        Point point2 = GeoJson.point(0.0, 0.1);
        Point point3 = GeoJson.point(0.1, 0.0);
        Point point4 = GeoJson.point(0.0, 0.0);
        Polygon location = GeoJson.polygon(point1, point2, point3, point4);

        place.setLocation(location);

        placeDAO.save(place);
        List<Place> places = shopDAO.find().asList();
    }
}
```

You can create your 2dsphere index and perform $intersect queries no problem.

Comment: I ended up creating a hashmap like `private HashMap<String,Object> loc = new HashMap<String,Object>()` and then put the whole `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double[]>> coordinates` as a value into the map. But that's a workaround. Seems like a bug in Morphia?

Comment: This will not work, because the GeoJSON format for polygon is {"type":"Point","coordinates":[....]} and with your solution you're getting {"Point":[...]}. Can you give an example of saving one polygon into db with your solution? Anyway, this is not a bug in Morphia but in my opinion documentation is not sufficient. Hopefully we can provide enough information for other people who stumble upon this problem.

Comment: in the HashMap that I mentioned. I put two key value pairs. `loc.put("type", "Polygon");
loc.put("coordinates", coordinates);`

here coordinates is a collection of points of type  `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double[]>> `

Comment: Oh in that case you're right, this might actually work. But is there any reason why not to use Morphia provided GeoJson factory?

Comment: The choice I made was because of the use case I had. I am using an algo which returns `ArrayList<Double[]>`. So I saved up some processing and heap space.